# Joi schema custom validator is not executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

If the field value (name) is empty string(''), I want the Joi schema to return null. Why doesn't the *custom* validator logic in the following Joi schema run?

I noticed that custom validator is not executing if the value of a key is empty string (''). Is there a fix for this problem?

```js
const Joi = require('joi');

const schema = Joi.object()
  .keys({
    name: Joi.string().optional().trim().allow(null, '').custom((value, helpers) => {
      console.log('-------------------', value)
      if (value === '') {
        return null;
      }
      return value;
    }),
  });

// steps to run
const input = {
  name: '', // Empty string
};

const result = schema.validate(input);
console.log(input, result.value);
// expected: {name: null}
// actual: {name: ''}
```